# Base table or view not found: 1146

Tags: laravel

I created migration successfully but can't see table in the database, when I go for "PHP artisan migrate" I am facing an error stated:

Base table or view not found: 1146 pakishops.advertisement does not exist.

here is migration code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdvertisementTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('advertisement', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');

                $table->integer('shop_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('shop_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('shops')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

                $table->string('image')->default('default.jpg');
                $table->datetime('starting_date');
                $table->datetime('ending_date');
                $table->boolean('is_paid');
                $table->boolean('is_active');

                $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
     Schema::dropIfExists('advertisement');
    }
}
```

What should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Change `table()` method:

```
Schema::table
```

To `create()`:

```
Schema::create
```

`table()` method changes existing table. `create()` creates new table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#migration-structure

Comment: Thanks Alexey Mezenin you were really helpful

Comment: @AsifNawaz If this answered your question please will you mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem in code:

To create table the migration file there should be `create()` method instead of `table()` method of `Schema`.

How it happened?

you must have called

```
php artisan make:migration add_votes_to_users_table --table=users
```

Instead you just need to call

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

`table` method can be used to alter the table and `create` method is used to create the table.

happy to help :) :) :)